# horizontal aligned div in div

Tags: html, css

I've tried to align horizontally the `galleria-image` with `table-cell` and floats but with no success. Anyone knows how to do this. There could me more or less of those `<div class="galleria-image">` which I would like to have horizontally centered.

```
<div class="galleria-thumbnails-container">
    <div class="galleria-thumbnails-list">
        <div class="galleria-thumbnails">
            <div class="galleria-image active">
                <span class="img"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="galleria-image">
                <span class="img"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="galleria-image">
                <span class="img"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.galleria-thumbnails-container {
    background-color:orange;
}
.galleria-thumbnails-list {
    display: table;
    position: relative; 
}
.galleria-thumbnails {
    height: 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100% ! important;
    display: table-row;
}
.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    width: 20px;
}
</style>
```

fiddle here --> http://jsfiddle.net/RsbP6/

what I have: [image]

what I would like to get: [image]

thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `margin: 0 auto;` to `.galleria-thumbnails-list` css

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RsbP6/1/)